# How can refresh UIView in UITabBarController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm stack on refreshing view in TabBar. The UIView is read only first time I pressed the TabButton and does not "viewDidLoad" next time. I want to refresh UITableView every time I pressed the button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok Found a solution (just right after i posted this here)

add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View appears");
}
```

to your ViewController and you will see that this method will be called, by clicking the TabButton ;)